# Golang: Is there a way to modify one of the multi-value return parameters in one line?

Tags: go

I am trying something relatively simple in Go - convert a string to integer and then double it:

```
myInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(args[1])
doubleArg := myInt * 2
```

Since `Atoi()` returns two parameters (the integer and `err`), I am using `myInt, _ :=` to retrieve the value of the integer. I would like to double it (hence the 2nd line) but can't do all in one line:

```
myInt, _ := strconv.Atoi(args[1]) * 2
```

gives me:

```
multiple-value strconv.Atoi() in single-value context
```

However, from my experience with most other languages it seems like a lot of boilerplate to have to do this in two lines. Is this just a limitation I'll have to deal with, or is there a better way to write my code?

Comment: I'm not sure how one additional line is "a lot of boilerplate". There is also a problem inherent in the question: you're ignoring errors and trying to multiply the result of `Atoi` which may not be the value you're expecting if the call fails.

Comment: Go does not have a capability of doing this.  If it returns two args, and you want to modify one, you need to assign them to vars and then modify on the second line.  On a side note, you _really_ shouldn't be ignoring that error variable return from `Atoi`.

Comment: **Don't fight with Go, just embrace it if you're going to use it.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two lines of code is not really that much. But if you have to do the same thing many times in your code, you might as well write your own version of the conversion then multiplication function. This function can do error checking, and the real work.